# Contextual filter that lists users who share a taxonomy term with current user?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that lists all user profiles. At registration, every user selects, from a 'sector' taxonomy, the sector they themselves do business in. They also select from the same 'sector' taxonomy to record what sectors they want to do business with. So their user profiles may look like this:

```
uid: 1
name: fred
sector in: arts
sectors to do business with: tech

uid: 2
name: alex
sector in: tech
sectors to do business with: design
```

I want a view to list all the users that do business in the sectors that the current user wants to do business in.

So, using the above profiles, if Fred was looking at the view, Alex's profile would be displayed because the filter would be:

```
sector == tech
```

Obviously, the filter needs to be dynamic. It needs to grab the 'sectors to do business with' field from Fred's user profile. I think I need a contextual filter, but how do I configure it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have two fields on your user profile called **field_working_in** and **field_want_to_work_with** execute the following steps:

- Add a **Users** view at admin/structure/views/add and set Display Format as **Table**
- Add two fields **User: Name** and **User: Working in**
- Add relationship with  **User: Working in**
- Add relationship with **Taxonomy term: User using Want to work with**
- Add a contextual filter: **User: uid** with *Provide Default Value* and *Type:* **User ID form logged in User** and set a relationship with **field_want_to_work_with** (see screenshot)
- Under **FILTER CRITERIA** Add the following filter to exclude the current user from the results: `User: Current (No)`

Export of view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'user_sections';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'User sections';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'User sections';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relationship: User: Working in (field_working_in) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_working_in_tid']['id'] = 'field_working_in_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_working_in_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_working_in';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_working_in_tid']['field'] = 'field_working_in_tid';
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: User using Want to work with */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_want_to_work_with_user']['id'] = 'reverse_field_want_to_work_with_user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_want_to_work_with_user']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_want_to_work_with_user']['field'] = 'reverse_field_want_to_work_with_user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_want_to_work_with_user']['relationship'] = 'field_working_in_tid';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User: Working in */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['id'] = 'field_working_in';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['table'] = 'field_data_field_working_in';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['field'] = 'field_working_in';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['element_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['delta_offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_working_in']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_want_to_work_with_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: User: Current */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['id'] = 'uid_current';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['field'] = 'uid_current';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['value'] = '0';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'user-sections';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'User sections';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
$translatables['user_sections'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('User sections'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('term from field_working_in'),
  t('field_want_to_work_with'),
  t('Name'),
  t('All'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

[image]

Comment: On bullet point 5, what do you mean by 'and set a relationship with field_want_to_work_with'?

Comment: Updated with a screenshot to clarify

Comment: hmm ok just saw that you added the tag that this is for drupal 8. not sure if this will work in that version  :)

Comment: Yea, I saw version 7 in your export and thought I'd better add a tag. I don't have the 'Relationship' select list that you have circled?

Comment: Just trying in d8 now and I did got the relationship field but it seems only when I first entered the contextual filter and then the relationships. right now fiddling around with the relationships but there is some weird stuff going around with Unknown column 'entity_id'  errors which is causing me to not saving the view after some changed.